# Can i decrease the time complexity using dynamic programming?

Tags: java, dynamic-programming

I have an array of Strings and among them one string is,

```
String s = "66678889966";
```

and I need to output it as 60078009060

i.e; I am making consecutive repeated chars as zero keeping the starting char.

Not only that string, all other strings as well, so I can't avoid outer loop to iterate over all those strings.

I solved this using a naive approach. Actually, I am solving a problem that includes another loop with an array of strings like this. Including my inner loop, it goes up to O(n^2) which is not acceptable.

```
BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(newInputStreamReader(System.in));
String s[], s1[];
s = bf.readLine().trim().split("\\s+");
s1 = bf.readLine().trim().split("\\s+");
BigInteger sb = new BigInteger(s[1]);
BigInteger sb1 = new BigInteger(s1[1]);
BigInteger indexIncre = new BigInteger("1");
BigInteger first = new BigInteger(s[1]);
BigInteger last = new BigInteger(s1[1]);
BigInteger length = last.subtract(first);
BigInteger summation = new BigInteger("0");
for (index = new BigInteger("0"); 
        !index.subtract(length).toString().equals("1"); 
        index =index.add(indexIncre)) {
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(first.toString());
    int len = str.length();
    char c = str.charAt(0);
    for (int i = 1; i < len; i++) {
        if (str.charAt(i) == c) {
            str.setCharAt(i, '0');
        } else
            c = str.charAt(i);
    }
    first = first.add(indexIncre);
    summation = summation.add(new BigInteger(str.toString()));
}
BigInteger modulo = BigInteger.valueOf((long) Math.pow(10, 9) + 7);
System.out.println(summation.mod(modulo));
```

For example 
**Input**

```
1 8
2 12
```

**output**

```
49
```

This is in the form of

**Input**
  NL L 
  NR R

The range of NL,L,NR,R are

1≤NL,NR≤10^5 
 1≤L≤R<10^100,000

Modified value is `f(x)`

```
f(8)=8,f(9)=9,f(10)=10,f(11)=10,f(12)=12
```

and modulo the sum of all these `f(x) by 10^9+7`

NL is the length of left-most string and L is the string, NR is the length of right most string and R is right most string. For example in the question length of number string 8 is 1 and the length of number string 12 is 2. The total number of strings are 8,9,10,11,12

Comment: @Anshu -- please don't undo all my edits

Comment: @Anshu he did it correctly

Comment: Have you considered using a `StringBuilder` and something like `StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("66678889966");
  for (int i = 1; i < sb.length(); i++) {
   for (int j = i - 1; i < sb.length() && sb.charAt(i) == sb.charAt(j); i++) {
    sb.setCharAt(i, '0');
   }
  }
  System.out.println(sb);`?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch what are you saying

Comment: Ok @antony as you suggested..my changes are not in the question..ok

Comment: That looks like too much code for what you are trying to do. `StringBuilder` is mutable, and the example does what you said you wanted (and should be much faster).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch what want much faster than this, see the constraints they are very large

Comment: I need a much faster algorithm/logic than this. I am thinking of using dp but not getting idea on how to  use

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a total of 'n' strings. Let's assume they are of an average 'm' length.

You will have to touch each character of each string at least once in order to know whether you have to zero out that particular character or not. Therefore the best complexity that you can achieve is O(m * n), which is quadratic.

O(m * n) is the same complexity that you would get by iterating in nested loop approach. Hence, you cannot do better than that by employing dynamic programming/memoization.

Comment: Is there any other way we can decrease the time complexity

Comment: Currently i am getting 6 sec for larger inputs and i want to get down them to a maximum of 3 sec

Comment: @antony: You can parallelize the operation if clock time is your concern. It can improve time when you have a large number of strings and you have idle processors up for use.

Comment: @antony: Multithreading, Multiprocessing, Distributed Computing... whatever you need and can afford.

Comment: Multithreading,MultiProcessing,Distributed Computing ..paralled things should not be used is the constraint

Comment: Any other alternative solution

Comment: @antony: Complexity wise, there is none. What is the problem with multithreaded approach?